# Customizing a single element in a Dokuwiki page

Tags: css, dokuwiki

Is it possible to customize the style of a single element in a dokuwiki page? For example, I'd like to change the background colour of a single `<code>` block, on a single page.

It seems that I can add a class `myClass` to the element like this:

```
<code myClass>
print "This is some code\n";
</code>
```

But I have no way to modify the class with css. **I don't have permission to edit the wiki-wide css files**. Is there any way a regular contributor can customize an element like that?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to do this is by [enabling html embedding](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:htmlok) in `../conf/local.php`.

This is a security risk, but not a problem since this wiki isn't exposed to the Internet.

Now, I can put something like this at the top of the page:

```
<HTML><style>
.code{
   background-color: red !important;
}
</style></HTML>
```